# Handle session expiration, Laravel with Vue and Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-7

I have an admin area and one for normal users. Right now when my session expire I get redirect from admin area to home page, and I have to refresh the page to redirect me to `/login`. PS. I am using Vue.js for front-end.

I want to be redirected to my /login page when session expire instead of homepage, which should not be visible then.

**web.php**

```
// Admin routes
Route::middleware(['can:admin'])->group(function () {
  // all routes for admin, and when my session expire I get redirected from here
}


Route::middleware('guest')->get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

// Normal user routes
Route::middleware('auth')->get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts.app');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('layouts.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('admin', function ($user) {
        return !empty($user->roles()->where('admin_area', true)->first());
    });

    Gate::define('normal', function ($user) {
        return !empty($user);
    });
}
```

One solution is to catch `403` error with `axios` and to do a hard refresh.  But I know that's not really ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case the solution you proposed sounds fine to me. If you are doing AJAX requests anyway, why not react to the 403 Unauthorized Response and redirect the user to you login page!

One way to achieve this would be to use [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), if you are using axios.

Here is a short code snippet from their docs:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
    }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    if(error.response.status === 403) {
        // redirect to login page
        window.location.href = "/login";
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

For anybody else:

I think the file you are looking for might be `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

Here you will find the following lines of code:

```
/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

as you can see, non json requests should be redirected to a route named `login`. So make sure that the route to your login page is also named `login` or change Authenticate.php accordingly.

Comment: I have this code in Authenticate.php, I also updated the post with the route for login. About my solution, I have to catch the error 403 in all my requests and to do a hard refresh, which is a lot to edit,  and a lot of redundant code.